# $(function(){...}); nested in (function(){...})();

Tags: jquery, function

Have picked up some jQuery code from a previous developer and am seeing the following a lot in our framework:

```
(function(){
$(function(){
    ...
});
})();
```

I understand the use of the self-executing function in our modular pattern, but I'm confused by the nesting of the other function. Can someone explain the purpose of this in general?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of thing can be used to enforce encapsulation in JavaScript.

In JavaScript, variables are functionally scoped:

```
var a = 10;
function() {
    var a = 20;
    alert(a); // output is 20
}
alert(a); // output is 10
```

This is sometimes used for [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) or [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding). For example, consider the following javascript, which counts how many times a button was clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("MyButton");
button.onclick = function() { count++ };
</script>
```

Since it is not in a function, the `count` variable is exposed, and could be reset as easily as:

```
count = 0; // oh no! now we don't know how many times it was clicked
```

To prevent this, the code should be in a self-executing function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var button = document.getElementById("MyButton");
    button.onclick = function() { count++ };
}());
</script>
```

Now the `count` variable is safely tucked away in the scope of this self-executing function; no one can change its value... uh, or read it... but it's just an example.

If this makes some sense, you might want to read about [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: But all of the code except for `$(...)` is already in a function, so this specific example would seem to be useless — possibly a blind application of the pattern you describe.

Comment: @Kevin Reid - I'm inclined to agree.

Answer (score 2):

`$(function () { ... });` is a short hand for binding to `document.ready`.  It's a way to make sure the DOM is loaded before modifications begin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you combine the self-executing function with document.ready, like ($(function(){...})(); and skip nesting the functions?

Comment: @ellenchristine - You don't actually have to have the self executing function at all unless you're using it to encapsulate variables / generate closures on purpose.  You can just call `$(function () { ... })` and it will bind to the DOM ready function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can provide some insight but I cannot understand its purpose

The inner function (shown below) is the same as `$(document).ready()`  Reference to [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(function(){
    ...
});
```

The outer function is simply a closure to execute the `$(document).ready()` function, but the purpose in this example seems to be useless.